# while installing phone gap using npm install-g phonegap

Tags: cordova

```
c:\>npm install -g phonegap
npm WARN deprecated deflate-crc32-stream@0.1.2: module has been merged into crc32-stream
> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\CNTUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\CNTUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

npm ERR! ws@0.4.31 install: `(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ws@0.4.31 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ws package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ws
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd c:\
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Try re installing new node version so that it updates the npm and try again. if it doesn't work then try installing a downgraded version. I mean a specific version. Eg: npm install -g phonegap@3.5.0-0.20.10